# Tomcat keeps redirecting to a servlet I even after changing the URL

Tags: java, forms, macos, tomcat, servlets

I have a Netbeans 11.1 project with Tomcat 9.0.34 on macOS 10.15.4
I have an html file with a form with a

`[...] action=signUpClient[...]`

it calls the signUpClient servlet.
I did change it afterwards to another servlet, RegistrarCliente.

Doesn't matter how many times I change the servlet name in the html form, when I press the submit button it keeps redirecting me to the first servlet.
Why does this keep happening? 
Also, I have a different html page which has to redirect me to another completely different servlet and it doesn't work, every form keeps sending me to the `signUpClient` servlet.

Can anyone help me out? I've tried removing and reinstalling with different Netbeans and Tomcat versions with no luck so far.

Comment: Please provide us with some code. Most likely there is a typo or a missconfiguration. Consider update your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. I was running a Java Maven Project on Netbeans 11.1 with Tomcat 9.0.30. I click on the project > Clean, refreshed Tomcat and it started working again.